# Zoomable Treemap in d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ for my data visualisation.
This tree map is displaying four boxes named east,west,south,north with grey background at starting as parent node.
I want to give different color to east,west ,south,north, I tried changing css of parent but its applying to all. How to give different background to each of those section??

Comment: [This question](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) might be a better start.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or example to show us what you have?

Comment: @lars :  i tried ur link which explains how to color. bt dont know why its not working also it is not giving any error.

Comment: As jczaplew says, at this point we really need to see some code to tell you what's going on.

Comment: i have copy pasted the code from view source just to see how it works, and it is working perfectly fine so it will be help full for me if you check the code from above link. My code,CSS and code used in above link for demo is exact same.